# Verilog: Always statement, trigger on positive edge for 3 bit variable

Tags: verilog

My project is to use a CPDL, which I am programming in verilog to commutate a BLDC motor. Part of that process is to read in hall sensors A,B,C.

I want to count the amount of positive edges on A,B or C. I have a 3 bit variable [2:0] hallIn to store these inputs. The code below works in a modelsim simulation but not on an actual chip. How come? What is the proper way to do this? The error message I get is: 73:12:73:55|Can't mix posedge/negedge use with plain signal references

```
always @ (posedge hallIn[2] or hallIn[1] or hallIn[0])
```

Comment: This is not a Verilog programming issue, but *how to do hardware design* issue. Try asking on https://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: your block is triggered by positive edge only of bit [2] and, actually by both edges (changes) of bits [1] and [0]. I doubt it works in modelsim correctly. You probably did not do enough testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synthesize code is a subset of what Verilog will let you do. Synthesizable code requires a coding structure that can be mapped to logic cells. Non-synthesizable code is intended for behavior modeling and test benches.

Flip-flops should normally be synchronized by a common clock source; not data.  With a clock, you could detect the posedge data by comparing the inputs current value against it previous value.

Example:

```
assign posedge_detected = |(hallIn & ~prev_hallIn);

always @(posedge clock) begin
  if (reset) begin
    prev_hallIn <= 3'b000;
    count <= 16'h0000;
  end
  else begin
    prev_hallIn <= hallIn;
    count <= count + posedge_detected;
    end
  end
end
```